# I have 2 onClick functions being run, one right after another but ones not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functions being ran for onClick, lottery and createAlert. createAlert is not creating the alerts. What have I done wrong? Also if anyone can tell me how to change the lottery function back to taking the Id of the button as a argument that would be appreciated because when I added the second function to the onClick it stopped working.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactInfo from "./ResultInfo";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 10,
      ran: "",
      id: "",
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1),
      userPoint: 0,
      pcPoint: 0,
      roundLimit: 10,
      roundWinner: ""
    };
    this.createAlert = this.createAlert.bind(this);
    this.lottery = this.lottery.bind(this);
  }
  createAlert = () => {
    if (this.state.roundWinner === "User") {
      return (
        <Alert variant="success" dismissible>
          <Alert.Heading>Congrats!</Alert.Heading>
          <p>Nice Going Man, You won!</p>
          <hr />
          <p>
            The score is You:{this.state.userPoint} to PC:{this.state.pcPoint}
          </p>
        </Alert>
      ); 
    } else {
      return (
        <Alert variant="success" dismissible>
          <Alert.Heading>Too Bad!</Alert.Heading>
          <p>Better Luck Next Time!</p>
          <hr />
          <p>
            The score is You:{this.state.userPoint} to PC:{this.state.pcPoint}
          </p>
        </Alert>
      );
    }
  };

  lottery = (event, temp) => {
    const users_choice = event;
    this.setState({ id: users_choice });
    const PC_choice = ["Paper", "Rock", "Scissors"][
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    ];
    this.setState({ ran: PC_choice });
    console.log("pc; state =", this.state.ran, "but variable =", PC_choice);
    console.log("user: state =", this.state.id, "but variable =", users_choice);
    if (
      (users_choice === "Paper" && PC_choice === "Rock") ||
      (users_choice === "Rock" && PC_choice === "Scissors") ||
      (users_choice === "Scissors" && PC_choice === "Paper")
    ) {
      this.setState(({ userPoint, roundWinner }) => ({
        userPoint: userPoint + 1,
        roundWinner: "User"
      }));
    } else if (users_choice === PC_choice) {
      this.setState(({ roundWinner }) => ({
        roundWinner: "Draw"
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(({ pcPoint, roundWinner }) => ({
        pcPoint: pcPoint + 1,
        roundWinner: "PC"
      }));
    }
  };


  render(props) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h5>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h6> Select Your Weapon </h6>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Paper"); this.createAlert();}}
                  id="Paper"
                >
                  Paper
                </Button>{" "}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Rock"); this.createAlert();}}
                  id="Rock"
                >
                  Rock
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Scissors"); this.createAlert();}}
                  id="Scissors"
                >
                  Scissors
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>

        <ReactInfo
          id={this.state.id}
          ran={this.state.ran}
          roundWinner={this.state.roundWinner}
          userPoint={this.state.userPoint}
          pcPoint={this.state.pcPoint}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `createAlert` function is called in `onClick` callback and it return alert jsx inside this callback, that why your alert was not rendered in your component.
2. In `lottery`, there are 5 `setState` statement, it violates DRY principle.
   You should try this:

```js
...

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 10,
      ran: "",
      id: "",
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1),
      userPoint: 0,
      pcPoint: 0,
      roundLimit: 10,
      roundWinner: ""
    };
    this.lottery = this.lottery.bind(this);
  }

  lottery = (event, temp) => {
    const users_choice = event;
    let userPoint = this.state.userPoint, pcPoint = this.state.pcPoint, roundWinner = this.state.roundWinner
    const PC_choice = ["Paper", "Rock", "Scissors"][
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    ];
    
    if (
      (users_choice === "Paper" && PC_choice === "Rock") ||
      (users_choice === "Rock" && PC_choice === "Scissors") ||
      (users_choice === "Scissors" && PC_choice === "Paper")
    ) {
      userPoint += 1
      roundWinner = "User"
    } else if (users_choice === PC_choice) {
      roundWinner = "Draw"
    } else {
      pcPoint += 1
      roundWinner = "PC"
    }
    this.setState({ id: users_choice, ran: PC_choice, userPoint, pcPoint, roundWinner });
  };


  render(props) {
    return (
      <>
        {
          this.state.roundWinner === "User" ?
            (
              <Alert variant="success" dismissible>
                <Alert.Heading>Congrats!</Alert.Heading>
                <p>Nice Going Man, You won!</p>
                <hr />
                <p>
                  The score is You:{this.state.userPoint} to PC:{this.state.pcPoint}
                </p>
              </Alert>
            ) : (
              <Alert variant="success" dismissible>
                <Alert.Heading>Too Bad!</Alert.Heading>
                <p>Better Luck Next Time!</p>
                <hr />
                <p>
                  The score is You:{this.state.userPoint} to PC:{this.state.pcPoint}
                </p>
              </Alert>
            )
        }
        <div className="container">
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h5>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h6> Select Your Weapon </h6>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Paper")}}
                  id="Paper"
                >
                  Paper
                </Button>{" "}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Rock")}}
                  id="Rock"
                >
                  Rock
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="myButton"
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  size="md"
                  onClick={() => { this.lottery("Scissors"); this.createAlert();}}
                  id="Scissors"
                >
                  Scissors
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
        ...
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: This worked but it's now displaying in the div that I have the counter rendering in, in my index.js file. I should have realized that would happen. It's also not collapsing. Sorry, I am new to react.

Comment: Please up the code on codesandbox so I can see what you want. @dakben